# How to transfer the ownership of a Google Sheets document to another account outside of the Google Workspace organization without losing cell history?

Tags: google-drive, google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

I have a Google Workspace domain that I want to close in order to move completely to my a Google Workspace domain.

Under the old account there is an important Google Sheets document, a list of client computers, and I often look there to see who was the previous (or penultimate) user of a particular computer, or when a computer was moved from one user to another, by right-clicking and selecting "Show edit history". Another case when I need cell history is when I suspect misaligned copy-paste of values in the database and want to know the previous value of a cell and when it was changed.

How can I save, export or transfer ownership of this Google Sheets document data - specifically with the cell history - so that I can close my old Google Workspace account in order not to pay double (for the old and for the new domain).

I've tried transferring the ownership to my account in the new domain but Google Sheets won't let me - saying that this account is outside of the organization. I tried sharing the file to my other account and File > Make a copy, but the cell history is reset then. What other options do I have, besides manually writing out every single cell's every single change to some text document?

Answer (score 0):

The method of cross-domain transfer with preserving file IDs using Google Shared Drives is well described [here](https://www.tabgeeks.com/tabgeeks-blog/how-to-transfer-ownership-between-domains-in-google-drive).

Summary:

1. Setup Google Shared Drive.
2. Neutralize files' ownership in the Shared Drive.
3. Assign new ownership.

If you do not have access to Google Workspace (former G Suite), you can take advantage of ready-made solutions available in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/Transfer%20files) and also available here as a [web application](https://movefiles.app/).
The transfer of one or several files falls into the free quota of the above mentioned utilities.